# Gradle Build Failure when Connecting Flutter App to Firebase for Android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I am new to Flutter and currently trying to connect my Flutter app with Firebase for Android. However, when I try to build the project, I encounter the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
> Error while evaluating property 'extraGeneratedResDir' of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths' property 'extraGeneratedResDir'.
      > Querying the mapped value of provider(java.util.Set) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 59s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I followed the steps mentioned in the Firebase documentation for setting up Flutter with Firebase on Android: [Add Firebase to your Flutter app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android)

I have also ensured that my `build.gradle` files are configured correctly as shown below:
`/android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`/android/app/build.gradle`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    // ... (other configurations)

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // ... (other configurations)
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    // ... (other dependencies)
}
```

To better understand the issue, I have uploaded the project to GitHub: [TaskTrove](https://github.com/ShivangSrivastava/task_trove)

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this Gradle build error and successfully connect my Flutter app with Firebase for Android. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `google-services` version you're using is broken. It's not your fault.

Replace `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'` with `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15` and it should build. I cloned your project and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I appreciate your help. However, I've already tried updating the google-services version to 4.3.15 as you mentioned, but I'm still encountering the same error. Just to provide more context, I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 as my operating system.